# React-select does not recognise scss.module as className and classNamePrefix

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-select

Hi I just started using react-select and when I tried to apply className like this `className={styles.select}` when I inspect the page there is no class aplied to it. In the other hand if i set it like this `className='select'` it shows regulary as select__control, select__options etc. Is there a way that I can add module classes to react-select or is there a way I can put my class lets say `.select__control{background-color:red}` in scss where it will be recognized if I have left `className='select'`.

Answer (score 0):

e.g

You have `Select.module.scss`

```
.select {
  outline: 1px solid green;

  [class$="-control"] {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

And import

```
import style from './Select.module.scss';
// other 
return(<ReactSelect
   className={style.select}
/>)
```